# Caliburn Micro Screen Derived View Model Support Sub View Models?

Tags: windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

Using Caliburn Micro v2 is there a way of composing view models inside a screen such that the child view models get the OnInitialize, OnActivate() and OnDeactivate(bool) calls?

I have something like the following view model `WidgetsViewModel` used to display a screen.

```
public class WidgetsViewModel : Screen, IHandle<WidgetUpdateEvent>
{
    public ObservableCollection<WidgetSummaryViewModel> Widgets { get; set; }
...
    public void Handle(WidgetUpdateEvent theEvent)
    {
        // Update the specific widget in Widgets collection
    }
}

public class WidgetSummaryViewModel
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to move the handling of the `WidgetUpdateEvent` into the `WidgetSummaryViewModel` where it would sit more comfortably. Something like this:

```
public class WidgetSummaryViewModel : IHandle<WidgetUpdateEvent>
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public WidgetSummaryViewModel(IEventAggregator theEventAggregator)
    {
        theEventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Handle(WidgetUpdateEvent theEvent)
    {
        // Update this view model...
    }
}
```

What makes me uncomfortable is calling `Subscribe` inside the view model constructor. It would be much better if the screen was able to call the OnInitialize, OnActivate and OnDeactivate for me as it does for `Screen` derived view models. Is there some way to compose sub view models inside a screen derived based view model?

Comment: There is nothing that says you have too.. You can call it in OnInit or OnActivate, entirely up to you.  Usually just create a readonly private to hold the IEventAggregator _events and then assign only in the constructor then in the OnInit or OnActivate do the Subscribe(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make `WidgetsViewModel` a conductor:

   ```
   public class WidgetsViewModel : Conductor<WidgetSummaryViewModel>.Collection.AllActive
   {
   }
   ```
2. Update your data binding in `WidgetsView`:

   ```
   {Binding Items} instead of {Binding Widgets}
   ```
3. Derive `WidgetSummaryViewModel` from `Screen` and override all the methods you need.

For further information regarding Conductors, visit [Screens, Conductors and Composition](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition).